# Error compiling gcc with crosstool-ng

Tags: c++, c, gcc, crosstool-ng

Does somebody can help me solve this error? I was trying build arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi using ct-ng (version 1.23.0).

```
[ERROR]    /home/tomas/crosstool-ng-1.23.0/.build/src/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/ubsan.c:1474:23: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
[ERROR]    make[3]: *** [ubsan.o] Error 1
[ERROR]    make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ERROR]    make[2]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Installing pass-1 core C gcc compiler'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@338]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_gcc_core_backend[scripts/build/cc/100-gcc.sh@674]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_gcc_core_pass_1[scripts/build/cc/100-gcc.sh@227]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_cc_core_pass_1[scripts/build/cc.sh@35]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@653]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      'docs/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  If you feel this is a bug in crosstool-NG, report it at:
[ERROR]  >>      https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Make sure your report includes all the information pertinent to this issue.
[ERROR]  >>  Read the bug reporting guidelines here:
[ERROR]  >>      http://crosstool-ng.github.io/support/
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 23:56.63)
[23:57] / /home/tomas/crosstool-ng-1.23.0/ct-ng:147: recipe for target 'build' failed
make[1]: *** [build] Error 2
ct-ng:150: recipe for target 'build.3' failed
make: *** [build.3] Error 2
```

I am not sure if it's a gcc source code issue or if there is some configuration I can change in ct-ng to ignore this error.

```
[ERROR]    /home/tomas/crosstool-ng-1.23.0/.build/src/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/ubsan.c:1474:23: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
[ALL  ]           || xloc.file == '0' || xloc.file[0] == 'xff'
[ALL  ]                           ^~~~
[ALL  ]    Makefile:1085: recipe for target 'ubsan.o' failed
[ERROR]    make[3]: *** [ubsan.o] Error 1
```

Apparently that's the error right there.

Comment: Known bug: https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/735 You just need to upgrade the tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning from github instead of using the latest release solved the problem.